# Can't acquire HTML textarea input text using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

I have an HTML file using a `<textarea>` whose input I want to acquire using an Angular controller. Relevant HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="list">
  <textarea
    placeholder="Comments"
    id="feedback"
    ng-model="feedbackInput">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant code for my Javascript controller, which I feel like is on the right track, but produces the output:

```
$scope.finishSummary = function(){
    $scope.feedbackInput = "";
    console.log( "Feedback text = " + JSON.stringify($scope.feedbackInput) );
}
```

which produces the output:

> Feedback text= ""

I use a "console.log()" simply for debugging purposes, but I want to be able to see the actual input value from the `<textarea>`. I'm relatively new to coding in HTML and especially with using Angular, so excuse my inexperience with the matter. In the end I just want to check to see if there is no text in the `<textarea>`. Any suggestions with how to do this so I can inject the data input from `<textarea>` into Angular? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are resetting the value "", just remove that line,

```
$scope.finishSummary = function(){   
    console.log( "Feedback text = " + JSON.stringify($scope.feedbackInput) );
}
```

Also you are not calling the `finishSummary()` anywhere in your code, you can call it in ng-blur to see the changes of the variable

```
 <textarea
    placeholder="Comments"
    id="feedback"
    ng-blur="finishSummary()"
    ng-model="feedbackInput">
  </textarea>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gYk1TpBFz332SaaF1AkN?p=preview)**

Comment: Or move the console.log above the line that resets it! :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan I forgot to mention I have a button that calls finishSummary(). But I made the change you suggested, and now I get "Feedback text = undefined". Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Justin probably you are doing something wrong, check the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gYk1TpBFz332SaaF1AkN?p=preview

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sorry for the delay. I would love to mark it as "answered", but it's still giving me "undefined" for some reason, even though I have almost exactly what you have in the Plunker.